# Number of days between two timestamps

Tags: ios, swift, unix-timestamp

I want to get number of days between two timestamps but I am getting wrong value using this code.

Code :

```
    let currentDateTimeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0
    let firstDate = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: currentDateTimeStamp)
    let lastDate = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: individualCellData["joining_date"] as! TimeInterval) 
// First Method using extension
    let daysBetween = firstDate.interval(ofComponent: .day, fromDate: lastDate)
// Second method
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: lastDate, to: firstDate)

    extension Date {
        func interval(ofComponent comp: Calendar.Component, fromDate date: Date) -> Int {

            let currentCalendar = Calendar.current
            guard let start = currentCalendar.ordinality(of: comp, in: .era, for: date) else { return 0 }
            guard let end = currentCalendar.ordinality(of: comp, in: .era, for: self) else { return 0 }
            return end - start
        }
     }
```

I am getting timestamp from server in milliseconds. What is the correct way ?

Comment: For a starter, you should pass *seconds* to `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)`, not milliseconds.

Comment: @MartinR thanks:) it worked! Can you explain also ?

Comment: Just read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780353-init: *"Creates a date value initialized relative to 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 by a given number of **seconds.**"*

Comment: @MartinR Got it! Nice lesson for future.

Answer (score 4):

```
let date1 = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1507211263)//Thursday, 5 October 2017 13:47:43
let date2 = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1507556863)//Monday, 9 October 2017 13:47:43

var secondsBetween: TimeInterval = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1 as Date)
var numberOfDays = Int(secondsBetween / 86400)
print("There are \(numberOfDays) days in between the two dates.")
```

//FYI:  86400 seconds = 24 hr

Comment: Please note that some days have a [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), making them 86401 seconds long. Thus it is possible (though unlikely) for your formula to give the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Date {
    func timeStampToDay(timeStampInMillisecond:Double) -> Int {
        let date = Date()
        let todaysDateStamp = date.timeIntervalSince1970
        let timeStampDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStampInMillisecond / 1000)
        var secBetween = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: todaysDateStamp).timeIntervalSince(timeStampDate)
        return Int(abs(secBetween) / 86400)
    }
    func timeStampToDay(timeStampInSecond:Double) -> Int {
        let date = Date()
        let todaysDateStamp = date.timeIntervalSince1970
        let timeStampDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStampInMillisecond)
        var secBetween = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: todaysDateStamp).timeIntervalSince(timeStampDate)
        return Int(abs(secBetween) / 86400)
    }
}
```